# How to add new tags to Code Review?

Tags: support, tags

I see that there are not so many tags, and the available tags are not comparing all the technologies. For example, there is no tag for [play-framework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/play-framework), [ejjaberd](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/ejjaberd) and of course many others as well.

Comment: If you create a tag, and its meaning is not universally obvious and unambiguous, please also write something in its tag wiki. (Often, the easiest way to initialize the tag wiki is to take the text from the corresponding tag in Stack Overflow.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Creating tags is a privilege that comes with 150 rep.

We have found, through experience, that an explosion of tags is a bad thing on Code Review. Just because you can create a tag, does not mean you should.

Creating tags should be done with significant fore-thought, and probably discussion too:

- Code Review has a number of existing tags
- a number of tags have a history of mergers, burninations, and other murky activities
- tags on Code Review are not necessarily used the same way as they are on other sites (specifically Stack Overflow).

Are you fully aware of what they are, why the tags are like they are?

The answer Simon gave you included a link to the [Privileges help page](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags). Part of that page contains:

> Most common tags already exist on a mature site. You should always
>   favor existing tags; only create new tags when you feel you can make a
>   strong case that your question does cover a new topic that nobody else
>   has asked about before on this site.

Are we at the point where we have to ask you to make your (strong) case for your tag creation?

You have been in the process of creating multiple tags, close to a dozen, in the past few days. Many of the tags you have created are not appropriate, or have previous discussions on Meta. Some of them are good, though, so, this is not all bad.

[map](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) was a bad tag to create, there is already [hash-map](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-map), and map could mean other things to other people. At a minimum, you should have consulted with Meta (asked a question here) before creating that tag. There are many requests like this... in fact, there is a tag on Meta, for discussion around tags: [tags](/questions/tagged/tags).

[upload](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upload) is also a bad tag. What language is upload? What purpose does it serve?

Ask yourself, who would follow this tag, if I create it? How does it add value to the whole community? Does the new tag add more value than the cost of diluting existing tags?

There is a fine balance between creating tags that help organize the site, and allow people to find what they are looking for, and follow the things important to them.

Please slow down and be more communicative before adding tags.

Now, time for me to head off, and follow in your footsteps, cleaning up some mess.

Update:

- [playframework](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/playframework) is just [mvc](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/mvc) in a specific language
- [anorm](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/anorm) is a subset of data access abstraction. Not sure that it should be tagged at all. It is implied any time you have SQL in code.
- [connection](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/connection) is .... nothing special. There's already [socket](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/socket), and others.
- [upload](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/upload) is discussed already.
- [nio](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nio) is a subset of [io](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/io)

In general, language tags are good, but specific features of languages are bad, unless those features relate to broad concepts, like MVC, OOP, etc. so there are 'concept tags' that, when combined with the language, are useful...

If you think you can provide a good case for and of the above tags, I will be happy to discuss here in Meta. I may have been over-zealous in the clean out.... these things happen.

Also, remember, we are always avaialble in [the 2nd Monitor chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) if you want to discuss things.

Answer (score 10):

To create a tag, you [edit an existing question](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/posts/2012/edit) that you think could use the tag and add the tag to the taglist at the bottom, or add the tag when creating a new question.

It is not possible to create a tag without attaching it to a question.

For more information see [Privileges - Create Tags](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/create-tags).

Note that only users with at least 150 reputation can do this.