# [hash-map]->[hash-table]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, synonym-request

We have both [hash-map](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-map) and [hash-table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-table) in the system. I have been [trying to keep from having language-specific](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2075/31503) constructs [in the tags](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/2031/31503).

Not sure how this one slipped through... again.

I propose creating a synonym from [hash-map](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-map) to [hash-table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-table). This is better than burnination because new questions cannot recreate the tag.

Similarly, [dictionary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) -> [hash-table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-table)

Comment: How is this [tag:status-completed]?  Still two different tags, no synonym.  I've just updated the [tag:hash-map] tag wiki (since this one has the most questions belonging to it) so that this merge can be done.

Comment: [dictionary] still exists too.

Answer (score 10):

I say do it. [Wikipedia considers them the same thing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) and as far as I know, they are.

However, there might be a bit of confusion for any Java developers and that might be a drawback. [Apparently both exists as separate entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40471/differences-between-hashmap-and-hashtable), so we'll need to be prepared to explain that tags such as these are not language specific.

Comment: A good tag wiki should solve the Java particularity!

Comment: Java `Hashtable` is an old crap, it doesn't really count. AFAIK there's no reason to use it, ever (its synchronization is rarely useful and if so, then there's `Collections.synchronizedMap`). I guess, there are many people not knowing that it exists (and that's a good thing).

Answer (score 3):

## This needs moderator intervention

[image]

[image]

This is because [hash-set](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-set) -> [hash-table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-table) exists.
And since [map](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/map) -> [hash-map](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-map) exists, we can't synonym [hash-map](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-map) -> [hash-table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-table)/[dictionary](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dictionary) either.

Comment: and ..... Done!

Answer (score 2):

Yes, let's merge these - probably into [hash-map](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-map), as that's the one with most questions (by only a small margin).

I've copied the useful stuff from [hash-table](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hash-table) into it in readiness for the merge.

Definitely yes to the synonym once it's done.

(I don't understand why this question is [status-completed](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/status-completed); did it somehow get discompleted in the intervening years?)